# Amazon Product Advertising API Signing

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am writing an app on iOS that uses the Amazon API to display a list of products in a category.

The problem I'm having is in signing the API. I am using the advertising API in India, and am using scratchpad to test out the api call.

For the unsigned url generated by Amazon Scratch I have:

```
http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&SubscriptionId=IAMHIDINGTHISINFO&AssociateTag=HIDINGTHIS-XX&BrowseNodeId=1350388031&ResponseGroup=BrowseNodeInfo
```

For the signed I have:

```
http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId= IAMHIDINGTHISINFO&AssociateTag=HIDINGTHIS-XX&BrowseNodeId=1350388031&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&ResponseGroup=BrowseNodeInfo&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-11-21T16%3A06%3A05.000Z&Signature=LETSSAYITGENERATEDTHIS
```

Following the steps on Amazon's documentation on signing the, I get the final canonical form as:

```
GET webservices.amazon.co.in/onca/xml AWSAccessKeyId= IAMHIDINGTHISINFO&AssociateTag=HIDINGTHIS-XX&BrowseNodeId=1350388031&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&ResponseGroup=BrowseNodeInfo&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-11-20T22%3A55%3A41.000Z
```

Which is following their steps EXACTLY. I prepend `GET\nwebservices.amazon.co.in\n/onca/xml\n` to the byte order the rest of the keys and then use HMAC SHA-256 to obtain the signature. Despite this, I get an incorrect signature generated.I know the hashing algorithm I use is correct since when I hash the example that they give in the documentation, it generates the exact hash (I am using AWSSignatureSignerUtility from their iOS SDK).

Can someone please tell me if I should not prepend `GET\nwebservices.amazon.co.in\n/onca/xml\n` or if it should be something else?

Comment: I mainly need a help with figuring out whether my canonical form is correct or not, my hashing works correctly as per their documentation, but I'm not sure if the canonical form I'm signing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the problem with the help of [Signed Requests Helper](https://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html).

Apparently, I was supposed to prepend

```
GET\nwebservices.amazon.in\n/onca/xml\n
```

and not

```
GET\nwebservices.amazon.co.in\n/onca/xml\n
```